# What are the properties of this kind of Fourier transform when using it to solve Wave equqtion with Robin boudary data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am facinated by the following problem (Which is found in Budak & Samarskii's Book ***Collection of Problems on Mathematical Physics***, about on Page 53.):

Solve the following problem by using Fourier Transform with kernel $$K(x,\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\lambda \cos(\lambda x)+h\sin(\lambda x)}{\lambda^2+h^2}.$$
the problem is: 
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&u_t=a^2 u_{xx}, x,t>0,\\
&u_x(0,t)-hu(0,t)=-h\phi(t), t>0, h=\text{const.}>0,\\
&u(x,0)=0,x>0
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

I have never seen this kind of Fourier transform before, and I have trouble in figuring out its inverse transform. It seems like the combination of Fourier Sine tranform and Cosine transform. Can someone tell me what are the properties of this  "Strange" integral transform?  Or where I can find the refereces? In Budak's above book I found nothing about it.  Thanks in advance.